# SubViewTwoController not declared (obj-c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to find my way into Obj-C for iPhone programming using [this](http://theappleblog.com/2009/04/15/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/#) tutorial.
In the end, what ever menu point you choose, SubViewOne was displayed.

I want to change this and in the end SubViewTwo(.xib) should appear when tapping the menu point "Sub View Two"

So what i did was changing the second repeat of

```
SubViewOneController *subViewOneController = [[SubViewOneController alloc] init];  
    subViewOneController.title = @"Subview One";  
    [views addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                      @"Subview One",         @"title",  
                      subViewOneController,   @"controller",  
                      nil]];  
    [subViewOneController release];
```

to

```
subViewTwoController = [[SubViewTwoController alloc] init];  
    subViewTwoController.title = @"Subview Two";  
    [views addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                      @"Subview Two",           @"title",  
                      subViewTwoController, @"controller",  
                      nil]];  
    [subViewOneController release];
```

what gives me the error
"SubViewTwoController undeclared (first use in this function)

I am quite new to this language so i would really appreciate it if you would leave some suggestions with a short explanation!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just haven't declared the variable it should be:

```
SubViewTwoController *subViewTwoController = [[SubViewTwoController alloc] init];  
    subViewTwoController.title = @"Subview Two";  
    [views addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                      @"Subview Two",           @"title",  
                      subViewTwoController, @"controller",  
                      nil]];  
    [subViewOneController release];
```

the difference being:

```
SubViewTwoController *subViewTwoController
```

It also looks like the header file for SubViewTwoController is not included in the class, its a bit tough to tell with the limited amount of code you've posted.

You can include that header file like so assuming it is defined.

```
#import "SubViewTwoController.h"
```